# My assertEquals from phpunit says my strings are not equal but I have copied them and I think it is due to lines being added to the response

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

I am trying to run some tests using guzzle to prompt my server for the JSON response which I will compare against what I expect the response should be. The problem is I cannot get the response to match the expected result. I think it is mainly due to some syntax error but I don't know how to rectify this.

I have already tried adding in new lines manually to what the output should be but this just adds \n to the string.

Please see the consoles report below:

```
1) UserAgentTest::testGet
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'{"error":false,"user":{"id_customer":10,"name":"Nic","email":"nparmee@gmail.com","password":"$2y$15$YN5A58syg5iIuHJ.5BR6j.ZpHGASqZID4l6k.M3xgH9jSPlojhzGK","x_coord":"-29.82188!-29.79044","y_coord":"31.02221!30.80688","address_name":"Home!Not home","address":"11 Rapson Road!11 everton road","country":null,"province":"KwaZulu-Natal!KwaZulu-Natal","city":"Durban!Durban","suburb":"Morningside!Kloof","postcode":"2639!3620","account":"sole","vat_num":"","reg_id":"","phone_number":"0836661065"}}'
+'
+
+{"error":false,"user":{"id_customer":10,"name":"Nic","email":"nparmee@gmail.com","password":"$2y$15$YN5A58syg5iIuHJ.5BR6j.ZpHGASqZID4l6k.M3xgH9jSPlojhzGK","x_coord":"-29.82188!-29.79044","y_coord":"31.02221!30.80688","address_name":"Home!Not home","address":"11 Rapson Road!11 everton road","country":null,"province":"KwaZulu-Natal!KwaZulu-Natal","city":"Durban!Durban","suburb":"Morningside!Kloof","postcode":"2639!3620","account":"sole","vat_num":"","reg_id":"","phone_number":"0836661065"}}'

C:\wamp64\www\tests\UserAgentTest.php:32

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: It looks like "expected" value containt extra quotes `'`. Try to remove it. Could you show the code of you tests?

Comment: I thought so at first but it is actually just two lines above the rest but @Nicolai Fröhlich answer helped I originally was trying to add lines to the expected output instead of removing lines from the actual output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 **leading** line-breaks in the "actual" string:

```
+'
+
+{"error":false
```

You can strip whitespace from the beginning and the end of a string with PHP's `trim` function.

```
 self::assertEquals(trim($string1), trim($string2));
```

This will ensure there are no leading/trailing whitespace characters.

Additionally you might want to strip all newlines with `preg_replace`:

```php
self::assertEquals(
    trim(preg_replace('/\R+/', '', $string1)),
    trim(preg_replace('/\R+/', '', $string2))
);
```

Comment: Perfect this worked thank you very much. Both options worked very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the binary safe case-insensitive string comparison with `strcasecmp`

```php
$this->assertEquals(0, strcasecmp($expected, $actual));
```